# Add something almost to the end of a quoted string using sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I want to add something almost to string end using `sed`. For example, add "xxx" without quotes between last two symbols in:

```
string1="var1, var2"
```

To get:

```
string1="var1, var2xxx"
```

How do I do it?

Comment: This should better be asked over at https://unix.stackexchange.com. And http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: About "no attempt" - i don't know what symbols will be before last quotes, so I cannot just run 
    sed -i 's|var2"|var2xxx"|g'
The question is "how to insert string between two last symbols in line". 
I'm not sure that is SO simple task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` like that:

```
s='string1="var1, var2"'
sed 's/"$/xxx&/' <<< "$s"

string1="var1, var2xxx"
```

Regex `"$` matches `"` before end of line.